# Access The Form Class From A Class Library

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

By default, the .net framework does not allow you to access forms when you are in a class library project, for obvious reasons.

But if you really want to, is there a way that form and controls can be passed to functions that are in a class library.

eg

In WinForms project

```
Class Form1
    Sub Load()
        dim c1 as new Foo
        c1.bar(me.button1)
    end sub
End Class
```

In Class Library Project

```
Class Foo
    sub bar(byref c as Button)
        c.text="BAR"
    end sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer as soon as posting.

You simply add a reference to "System.Windows.Forms" which is not in the Class Library project by default.